# Latest Entry for everymonth grouped by a Column - Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with record size for various servers and along with date server was scanned.I need to get the latest entry for each server in each month.
How can i do it in impala sql..any help would be appreciated.

```
Data    Server  Size
11/4/2017   ABC 200
11/18/2017  ABC 700
11/25/2017  ABC 1009
12/4/2017   ABC 200
12/18/2017  ABC 700
12/20/2017  ABC 1100
1/4/2018    ABC 200
1/18/2018   ABC 700
1/20/2018   ABC 1009
11/4/2017   CAD 200
11/18/2017  CAD 700
11/25/2017  CAD 1009
12/4/2017   CAD 200
12/18/2017  CAD 700
12/20/2017  CAD 1100
```

result expected

```
Data    Server  Size
11/25/2017  ABC 1009
12/20/2017  ABC 1100
1/20/2018   ABC 1009
11/25/2017  CAD 1009
12/20/2017  CAD 1100
```

Comment: Make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Impala supports window functions, so you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by server, trunc(data, 'MONTH')
                                order by data desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

The above gives the latest value for each server.  For one row per month, remove `server` from the `partition by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(data, 'MONTH')
                                order by data desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that quick help... I got the below results              
Data     Server         Size
1/20/2018 ABC         1009
11/25/2017 CAD 1009  . The expectation was to get the details for every month as mentioned below,                                                                                 
 Data    Server  Size
11/25/2017  ABC 1009
12/20/2017  ABC 1100
1/20/2018   ABC 1009
11/25/2017  CAD 1009
12/20/2017  CAD 1100

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MONTH(data) AS month, MAX(DAY(data)) AS day, server
 FROM t
 GROUP BY MONTH(data), server) sub
ON (MONTH(t.data) = sub.month AND DAY(t.data) = sub.day AND t.server = sub.server)
```

Select the max day per month per server in a sub-query. Then join the results of the sub-query to the main table. This will eliminate rows that are not the most recent per month per server.

Tested here: http://rextester.com/QTIM39711

Comment: Thanks so much kbball. I will try this and share the outcome.

Comment: I am getting an error. Could not resolve table reference.should i give the table name as mentioned below,SELECT t.*
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MONTH(scandate) AS month, MAX(DAY(scandate)) AS day, cluster
 FROM tablename t
 GROUP BY MONTH(scandate), cluster) sub
ON (MONTH(t.scandate) = sub.month AND DAY(t.scandate) = sub.day AND t.cluster = sub.cluster)

Comment: Oh yes - you need to replace t with your table name. Did you see the linked example? It works for me and I don't think anything in there is SQL Server specific.

Comment: Got the below error message after the tablename qualifier were given. The Cloudera Impala with Native Driver database encountered an error while running this query.
[Simba][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: 
TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: 
Could not resolve column/field reference: 'scandata' )